# selected value from the dropdown using HTMX framework

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5, htmx, hyperscript

In my HTMX page, I have two dropdown menus. I want to include the selected values from both dropdowns in a GET request. I've noticed that HTMX automatically includes the current dropdown's request parameter with its value in the GET request. However, I need both values to be part of the URL.

I'm also utilizing jQuery. Can you please provide a solution using either HTMX or jQuery?

```
<select id="plan-id" name="planCode"
     hx-get="change.html?planCode=&durationCode=" hx-trigger="change" hx-target='#rental-id' hx-indicator=".htmx-indicator">

     <option value=“A">Plan A</option>
     <option value=“B”>Plan B</option>
     <option value=“C”>Plan C</option>
</select>
```

```
<option value="1">1 Years</option>
<option value="2">2 Years</option>
<option value="3">3 Years</option>
```

```

Tried this solution. But it did not work. HTMX log says correctly
Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong here?

```
document.getElementById('plan-id').addEventListener('change', function () {
      const selectedPlan = this.value;
      const selectedDuration = document.getElementById('duration-id').value;
      const url = `change.html?planCode=` + encodeURIComponent(selectedPlan) + `&durationCode=` + encodeURIComponent(selectedDuration);
      this.setAttribute('hx-get', url);
      htmx.logAll();
      htmx.trigger('#plan-id', 'get', { url: url });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the select boxes with form tag and include hx-get in it. HTMX should then include all values within the form as params.

Example:

```
<form>
    <select id="plan-id" name="planCode" hx-get="change.html" hx-trigger="change" hx-target='#rental-id' hx-indicator=".htmx-indicator" hx-include="[name='durationCode']">

        <option value=“A">Plan A</option>
        <option value=“B”>Plan B</option>
        <option value=“C”>Plan C</option>
    </select>


    <select id="duration-id" name="durationCode" hx-get="change.html" hx-trigger="change" hx-target="#rental-id" hx-indicator=".htmx-indicator" hx-include="[name='planCode']">

        <option value="1">1 Years</option>
        <option value="2">2 Years</option>
        <option value="3">3 Years</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Alternative solution (both select change and button submit will trigger request):

```
<form hx-get="change.html" hx-trigger="submit, change">
    <select id="plan-id" name="planCode" hx-target='#rental-id' hx-indicator=".htmx-indicator">
        <option value="A">Plan A</option>
        <option value=“B”>Plan B</option>
        <option value=“C”>Plan C</option>
    </select>

    <select id="duration-id" name="durationCode" hx-target="#rental-id" hx-indicator=".htmx-indicator">
        <option value="1">1 Years</option>
        <option value="2">2 Years</option>
        <option value="3">3 Years</option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Sorry to say that it is not working.  There is no GET request triggered when I change the selection. Even if it is working, it will not solve my issue.  The complete form has one POST request triggered by submit button and these two drop downs pulls a partial content when triggered by the change in the selection of two drop downs.   They are two different endpoints.

Comment: @moorsu I've updated my answer. You're right, seems like the previous solution is not working when using change trigger. Can you try the updated code? I've added hx-include which is another way to add additional params. Also you don;t have to include params in the url. They will be added automatically.

Comment: Ref: https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-include/

Comment: Thanks Mariodev!. That worked. Learnt a new thing today.

Comment: Also, tried another thing. (Added in the original question). But not sure why it was not working. htmx log says it is triggering. But inspect window did not show anything.

Comment: @moorsu I'm not sure about the custom js, but either way it's not the go-to approach when using htmx. That's the beauty, once you have a better grasp on how to use hx tags, you very rarely have to use custom js logic. 
FYI I've updated my answer with original idea, with some modifications, which should also work. Keep exploring htmx docs.. ;)

Comment: Thanks @mariodev. Good to know that we can use multiple triggers in hx-trigger attribute